# Toolbar ScrollFlags

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have this toolbar with PagerTabStrip.
I also have a RecyclerView inside that PagerTabStrip.
When I scroll my RecyclerView, My toolbar will Hide, and what's left is the PagerTabStrip.
You can Refer to the Youtube App.
My Problem is, When my Toolbar is half hidden, it stays half hidden.
Unlike with Youtube App, If its more than half hidden, It will hide it all automatically.
I hope you Understand it well guys.
Here is my code, Do I need to Change something to produce something like in YOutube App?

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/content_nav"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.application.toweelo.activity.Nav"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_nav">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/btnSelectLocation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp">

                    <com.application.toweelo.custom.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="My Location"
                        android:textColor="#54FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.application.toweelo.custom.CustomTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="Quezon City"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/title"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_searchplace_downarrow"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="false"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please put all of your xml code

Comment: try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from your appbarlayout

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're talking about is achieved through a **snap** flag.

### **snap**

**Scroll Up AND Down** fast scrolls up or down based on how much of the view is visible - if more than 50% - the view will scroll down, showing itself, if less - the view will hide; used with other flags as a further customization

Read more about it on my [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout_scrollflags/).